# how to locate and extract coordinates/data/sub-components of charts/map image data?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, gis, scikit-image

I'm working on creating a tile server from some raster nautical charts (maps) i've paid for access, and i'm trying to post-process the raw image data that these charts are distributed as, prior to geo-referencing them and slicing them up into tiles

i've got a two sets of tasks and would greatly appreciate any help or even sample code on how to get these done in an automated way.  i'm no stranger to python/jupyter notebooks but have **zero** experience with this type of data-science to do image analysis/processing using things like opencv/machine learning (or if there's a better toolkit library that i'm not even yet aware of).

i have [some sample images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phwL7.jpg) (originals are PNG but too big to upload so i encoded them in high-quality JPEGs to follow along/provide sample data).. here's what i'm trying to get done:

- validation of all image data.. the first chart (as well as last four) demonstrate what properly formatted charts images should looks like (i manually added a few colored rectangles to the first, to highlight different parts of the image in the bonus section below)

  - some images will either have missing tile data, as in the 2nd sample image, these are ALWAYS chunks of 256x256 image data, so should be straightforward to identify black boxes of this exact size..
  - some images will have corrupt/misplaced tiles as in the 3rd image (notice in the center/upper half of the image is a large colorful semi-circle/arcs, it is slightly duplicated beneath and if you look along horizontally you can see the image data is shifted and so these tiles have been corrupted somehow
- extraction of information, ultimately once all image data is verified to be valid (the above steps are ensured), there is a few bit of data i really need pulled out of the image, the most important of which is

  - the 4 coordinates (upper left, upper right, lower left, lower right) of the internal chart frame, in the first image they are highlighted in a small pink box at each corner (the other images don't have them but they are located in a simlar way) - NOTE, because these are geographic coordinates and involve projections, they are NOT always 100% horizontal/vertical of each other.
  - the critical bit is that SOME images container more than one "chartlet", i really need to obtain the above 4 coordinate for EACH chartlet (some charts have no chartlets, some two to several of them, and they are not always simple rectangular shapes), i may be able to generate for input the number of chartlets if that helps..
  - if possible, what would also help is extracting each chartlet as a separate image (each of these have a single capital letter, A, B, C in a circle that would be good if it appeared in the filename)
- as a bonus, if there was a way to also extract the sections sampled in the first sample image (in the lower left corner), this would probably involve recognize where/if in the image this appears (would probably only appear once per file but not certain) and then extracting based on its coordinates?

  - mainly the most important is inside a green box and represents a pair of tables (the left table is an example and i believe would always be the same, and the right has a variable amount of columns)
  - also the table in the orange box would be good to also get the text from as it's related
  - as would the small overview map in the blue box, can be left as an image

i have been looking at tutorials on opencv and image recognition processes but the content so far has been highly elementary not to mention an overwhelming endless list of algorithms for different operations (which again i don't know which i'd even need), so i'm not sure how it relates to what i'm trying to do.. really i don't even know where to begin to structure the steps needed for undertaking all these tasks or how each should be broken down further to ease the processing.